# fancybox fit image to the container

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I tried different answers from here but the results is still the same.. I am getting confused about this, I actually got the result i want. But I'm having problem in fancybox, i would like to fit my image to the container of  the fancybox. ( will upload photo)
 [image when not clicked yet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGeJk.png) / [image when inside fancybox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JArp.png)

Another sample, 
[image when not yet clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mne9J.png) /
[image inside fancybox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbAWf.png)
I am using this code

PS: this is in a forum, so images will be random..

```
$("#post_message_{vb:raw post.postid}").css({'transform': 'rotate(+90deg) translate(-56%)','transform-origin': 'bottom left','white-space': 'nowrap','max-height': '650px'});

$("#post_message_{vb:raw post.postid} ").css({'padding': '0% 0px 24% 0px','height': '0','display': 'table'});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#post_message_{vb:raw post.postid}").fancybox({                   
        beforeShow: function () {
            $(".fancybox-inner").css({
                "overflow-x": 'hidden'
            });
        },
        'autoSize': false,
        'fitToView': false,
        'autoResize': false,
        'autoCenter': false
    });               
});
```

Comment: But where is the problem? You do not know how to do smth like `.img { width: 100% }`??

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS to make your image 100% width or maybe set `object-fit: cover;` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit). Basically, jut do everything you would do without fancybox.